# Is there a name for this space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, terminology

I'm just asking if there is a name for the space of functions on $\mathbb R^n$ whose norm is defined by

$$ \|f\|=\|\hat f\|_{L^p} $$

for $p\in [1,\infty]$. I find it handy to give it a name when discussing the success/failure of Young's inequality on the Fourier transform, among other things.

Comment: @Giovanni I'm not asking about whether we identify functions equal a.e. (I'm always doing that). I'm asking whether there is a short term for the $L^p$ norm of the Fourier transform.

Comment: For $p=1,$ it is related to the algebra of Fourier transforms $\mathcal{F}L^{1}(\mathbb R^{n}).$ Some authors denotes as $A(\mathbb R^{n})$ as well.

Comment: It follows for the function itself that $f(x)\in L_q(\mathbb{R}^n)$, not so?

Comment: I guess this is true only when $p\in [1,2]$.

Comment: Sergei's comment is incorrect as FanZheng points out. Hausdorff-Young is not a characterization. I have never seen the space of functions whose FTs are p-integrable given any special name, so I would suggest just inventing some ad hoc notation within your paper and sticking to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the literature you can sometimes see them called **Fourier-Lebesgue** spaces, with notation $\mathcal{F} L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, consisting of the set of all tempered distributions whose norm (as you wrote) is finite.

See, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1730 and http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1444